# Tetrahedral Mesh file format in TETGEN

Tags: mesh-generation, mesh

`Ply` file formats is used to represent mesh structures in the TETGEN freeware package. All the examples I've seen of 'ply' meshes were used for triangular meshes.

Can we use ply formats to represent **`tetrahedral meshes`** as well ?

Any examples would be helpful ?

**PS :** I am new in this field  so any pointers for further understanding of the concepts would be really helpful. I am trying to simulate tissue deformation using FEM.

Comment: I came to know about  tetgen tool but it generates multiple files to represent the mesh structure.

Comment: I don't think that PLY files natively handle tetrahedrons. Although you can define new elements according to [this]( http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/)

Comment: @nicoguaro Could you suggest any method for generating a tetrahedral mesh file for an object ?

Comment: It would depend on how is your object define. But, I can suggest you to use [Tetgen](http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/) or [gmsh]( http://geuz.org/gmsh/)

Comment: @nicoguaro multiple file formats are generated in Tetgen. So we need to parse all the files to collect mesh structure info. Any standard file format for this representation ?

Comment: I have never used Tetgen, but I have used gmsh. I have enriched the mesh file with boundary conditions, and material information. But I have also used separate files for that.  If you're not sure, you should check input files for different FEA software like: Fenics, Abaqus, Ansys or Comsol. And see what things you like better.

Answer (score 1):

PLY is a generic file format that can store any mesh entities with information attached to it. It is mostly used to represent surfacic meshes, and this is what most softwares that use this file format will expect (including Tetgen), but in principle it can be extended to store tetrahedral meshes.

If you want to store tetrahedral meshes in PLY files and use Tetgen to manipulate them, you will need to modify Tetgen or use it as a library (Tetgen is implemented in C++).
An example of using tetgen as a library is the GEOGRAM library that I'm developping:
http://alice.loria.fr/software/geogram/doc/html/index.html

For reading and storing PLY files, I am using the following library:
http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/rply/

If you do not plan to modify Tetgen / use it as a library, another possibility is to write a file converter that converts between 'tetrahedral mesh stored in PLY file' and native tetrahedral meshes formats supported by tetgen.